# Return a String value from a function of type Future<String>

Tags: flutter

Building a app usage monitor app in flutter.
trying a plot a graph using App name and time spent in app.
I have package_name a apps but not the app_name itself, so I used **DeviceApp** package to get app_name using package_name.

the following code is the data given to the graph to plot

```
Future<void> initUsage() async {
    DateTime endDate = new DateTime.now();
    DateTime presentDate = new DateTime.now();
    DateTime startDate = DateTime(presentDate.year,presentDate.month,presentDate.day,0,0,0,1);

    try{
      List<AppUsageInfo> infoList = await AppUsage.getAppUsage(startDate, endDate);
      setState(() {
        _infos = infoList;
        _infos.sort((a,b) => b.usage.inSeconds.compareTo(a.usage.inSeconds));
      });
    } on AppUsageException catch (exception) {print(exception);}
  }




  @override
    build(BuildContext context) {
    
    appNameProvider(pn) async {
      Application apps = await DeviceApps.getApp(pn);
      return apps.appName.toString();
    }

    var data = [
      AppUsagePerDay(appNameProvider(_infos[0].packageName.toString()),_infos[0].usage.inMinutes),
      AppUsagePerDay(_infos[1].appName, _infos[1].usage.inMinutes),
      AppUsagePerDay(_infos[9].appName, _infos[9].usage.inMinutes),
      AppUsagePerDay(_infos[4].appName, _infos[4].usage.inMinutes),
    ];


    var series = [
      charts.Series(
        domainFn: (AppUsagePerDay appData, _) => appData.appName,
        measureFn: (AppUsagePerDay appData, _) => appData.usageTime,
        id: 'Apps',
        data: data,
      ),
    ];

    var chart = charts.BarChart(
      series,
      animate: true,
    );

    var chartWidget = Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 350.0,
        child: chart,
      ),
    );

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Chart")),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[chartWidget,
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So, how do I return a string from the function **appNameProvider** of type Future<string>.

The following errors pops up "The argument type 'Future' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'. "

Answer (score 0):

since appNameProvider(pn) is having  a type of Future you need to wait for the function to complete.
use it like this

```
var data=[];
String appName= await appNameProvider(_infos[0].packageName.toString());
data.add( AppUsagePerDay(appName,_infos[0].usage.inMinutes));
appName= await appNameProvider(_infos[1].packageName.toString());
AppUsagePerDay(appName,_infos[1].usage.inMinutes)
data.add( AppUsagePerDay(appName,_infos[1].usage.inMinutes));
appName= await appNameProvider(_infos[2].packageName.toString());
AppUsagePerDay(appName,_infos[2].usage.inMinutes)
data.add( AppUsagePerDay(appName,_infos[2].usage.inMinutes));
```